# Using Windows Authentication to call a Web API from a Windows Store application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication, iis-express, dotnet-httpclient, windows-store

Here is the context of my issue: I am developing a Windows Store application that will be side-loaded on several tablets our client is planning to use. This tablet app will make calls into a Web API which in turn will do CRUD operations with a repository (SQL Server via EntityFramework). Everything has to use Windows Authentication. The tablets are Dell running Windows 10. Each user will log in with its own active domain credentials. The tablet will pass the credentials to the Web API which in turn will pass them to the repository (database). Based on the credentials, the repository will determine the group the user belongs to and based on that, it will give access to resources the user is allowed to access.

My Web API works fine. I tested it with Fiddler. For the HTTP GET request, I want to test, I checked the "Automatically Authenticate" checkbox and I can see the three successive messages, first two returning with 401 and the third returning HTTP Code 200, along with the data I requested.

However, when I try to call it from my Windows Store app, I only send one GET Request, the first one. My Web API is hosted in IIS Express. At the advice of a very distinct member of this group, I configured IIS Express to expose the Web API using the IP address of my development machine rather than "localhost". Before doing this I wouldn't see any GET Requests hitting the server, not even the first one.

I know that Windows Authentication uses the NTLM scheme and it requires a negotiation process, hence the 3 messages Fiddler sends initially to the server?

How do I need to write my Web API Client code to bypass this negotiation? I spent all morning and afternoon reading solutions to my problem, here on SO and many other websites, but somehow, I still did not get it to work. I must be missing something and I don't know what. Here is my code on the Web API Client side:

```
var authHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
   Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials,
   ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic
};

var webApiClient = new HttpClient(authHandler)
{
   BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceUri), // _serviceUri is a string that looks like this "http://10.120.5.201:53045"
};

webApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = await webApiClient.GetAsync("api/user");
```

My call never returns from GetAsync, but in Fiddler, I can see only the first GET Requests being posted to the server. How can I get my client to follow up, behind the scenes, just like Fiddler does, and send the other two messages so that, eventually, the third one would return with a response HTTP 200 code and with the data I receive in Fiddler?

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be highly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the "Enterprise Authentication" setting was not set in the Capabilities tab of the Package.appxmanifest file of my app. It took me a while to figure out that that was the problem, but as soon as I checked it, my app started using Windows Authentication.